# Table Template with Rich UI

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I'm trying to find a html (or maybe flash) table template with rich ui features. I googled it, but couldn't find something that has a rich ui, also looked through jQuery, still no luck. Before going any deeper search, I believe someone may have suggestions for me.

Comment: Can  you specify what you mean by "Rich UI"?

Comment: @Pekka I mean I need a table template that is visually good and that enables me to customize it.

Comment: that is still not really a description. :) Do you want only a good-looking HTML style, or do you want additional functions?

Comment: @Pekka I can add some functionalities, so let's say I need a good-looking table:). thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for tables with lots of features you might want to take a look at [ExtJS Grids](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/#sample-3) (You have to click on Grids section to take a look at the demos).

jQuery has the [TableSorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) but that is a simpler option.